# Polish notation evaluate function

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am having hard-time with defining, or more likely translating my code from Ruby to evaluate calculations described as Polish Notations,
f.e. `(+ 3 2)` or `(- 4 (+ 3 2))`

I successfully parse the string to form of `ArrayBuffer(+, 3, 2)` or `ArrayBuffer(-, 4, ArrayBuffer(+, 3 2))`.

The problem actually starts when I try to define a recursive eval function ,which simply takes `ArrayBuffer` as argument and "return" an `Int`(result of evaluated application).

IN THE BASE CASE:
I want to simply check if 2nd element is an `instanceOf[Int]` and 3rd element is `instanceOf[Int]` then evaluate them together (depending on sign operator - 1st element) and return `Int`.

However If any of the elements is another `ArrayBuffer`, I simply want to reassign that element to returned value of recursively called eval function. like:
`Storage(2) = eval(Storage(2))`. (** thats why i am using mutable ArrayBuffer **)

The error ,which I get is:

```
scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I am of course not looking for any copy-and-paste answers but for some advices and observations. 
Constructive Criticism fully welcomed.

******** This is the testing code I am using only for the addition ********

```
def eval(Input: ArrayBuffer[Any]):Int = {

  if(ArrayBuffer(2).isInstaceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]]) {    
    ArrayBuffer(2) = eval(ArrayBuffer(2))
  }

  if(ArrayBuffer(3).isInstaceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]]) {    
    ArrayBuffer(3) = eval(ArrayBuffer(3))
  }

  if(ArrayBuffer(2).isInstaceOf[Int] && ArrayBuffer(3).isInstanceOf[Int]) { 
    ArrayBuffer(2).asInstanceOf[Int] + ArrayBuffer(3).asInstanceOf[Int]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste what code you have for the evaluation function?  That will make it easier to see where you're having issues and make the assistance more directed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few problems with your code:

- `ArrayBuffer(2)` means "construct an `ArrayBuffer` with one element: `2`".  Nowhere in your code are you referencing your parameter `Input`.  You would need to replace instances of `ArrayBuffer(2)` with `Input(2)` for this to work.
- `ArrayBuffer` (and all collections in Scala) are 0-indexed, so if you want to access the second thing in the collection, you would do `input(1)`.
- If you leave the the final `if` there, then the compiler will complain since your function won't always return an `Int`; if the input contained something unexpected, then that last `if` would evaluate to `false`, and you have no `else` to fall to.

Here's a direct rewrite of your code: fixing the issues:

```
def eval(input: ArrayBuffer[Any]):Int = {
  if(input(1).isInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]])
    input(1) = eval(input(1).asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]])
  if(input(2).isInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]])
    input(2) = eval(input(2).asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[Any]])

  input(1).asInstanceOf[Int] + input(2).asInstanceOf[Int]
}
```

(note also that variable names, like `input`, should be lowercased.)

---

That said, the procedure of replacing entries in your input with their evaluations is probably not the best route because it destroys the input in the process of evaluating.  You should instead write a function that takes the `ArrayBuffer` and simply recurses through it without modifying the original.

You'll want you `eval` function to check for specific cases.  Here's a simple implementation as a demonstration:

```
def eval(e: Seq[Any]): Int = 
  e match {
    case Seq("+", a: Int,      b: Int)      => a + b
    case Seq("+", a: Int,      b: Seq[Any]) => a + eval(b)
    case Seq("+", a: Seq[Any], b: Int)      => eval(a) + b
    case Seq("+", a: Seq[Any], b: Seq[Any]) => eval(a) + eval(b)
  }
```

So you can see that for the simple case of `(+ arg1 arg2)`, there are 4 cases.  In each case, if the argument is an `Int`, we use it directly in the addition.  If the argument itself is a sequence (`like ArrayBuffer`), then we recursively evaluate before adding.  Notice also that Scala's `case` syntax lets to do pattern matches with types, so you can skip the `isInstanceOf` and `asInstanceOf` stuff.

Now there definitely style improvements you'd want to make down the line (like using `Either` instead of `Any` and not hard coding the `"+"`), but this should get you on the right track.

And here's how you would use it:

```
eval(Seq("+", 3, 2))
res0: Int = 5

scala> eval(Seq("+", 4, Seq("+", 3, 2)))
res1: Int = 9
```

---

Now, if you want to really take advantage of Scala features, you could use an `Eval` *extractor*:

```
object Eval {
  def unapply(e: Any): Option[Int] = {
    e match {
      case i: Int => Some(i)
      case Seq("+", Eval(a), Eval(b)) => Some(a + b)
    }
  }
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
scala> val Eval(result) = 2
result: Int = 2

scala> val Eval(result) = ArrayBuffer("+", 2, 3)
result: Int = 5

scala> val Eval(result) = ArrayBuffer("+", 2, ArrayBuffer("+", 2, 3))
result: Int = 7
```

Or you could wrap it in an `eval` function:

```
def eval(e: Any): Int = {
  val Eval(result) = e
  result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on right to left stack-based evaluation:

```
def eval(expr: String): Either[Throwable, Int] = {
  import java.lang.NumberFormatException
  import scala.util.control.Exception._

  def int(s: String) = catching(classOf[NumberFormatException]).opt(s.toInt)
  val symbols = expr.replaceAll("""[^\d\+\-\*/ ]""", "").split(" ").toSeq
  allCatch.either {
    val results = symbols.foldRight(List.empty[Int]) {
      (symbol, operands) => int(symbol) match {
        case Some(op) => op :: operands
        case None => val x :: y :: ops = operands
        val result = symbol match {
          case "+" => x + y
          case "-" => x - y
          case "*" => x * y
          case "/" => x / y
        }
        result :: ops
      }
    }
    results.head
  }
}
```